# How to perform a logout for a user that logged in with his Apple Id?

Tags: node.js, swift, express, apple-sign-in

I'm trying to add an Apple Sign In feature to my app, but there is one obstacle, there is no information how to logout after the user logged in. I've tried to use this code, but seems like, despite the operation was set to Logout it still perform the Sign In operation:

```
let request = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest()

        request.requestedOperation = .operationLogout

        let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])

        authorizationController.performRequests()
```

And if I'm trying to get a new jwttoken and verify it on my backend side, it returns me an error message "Invalid Signature". It works fine if the status is not authorized.
So basically I need somehow to verify my token even if the status is authorized or logout.